# iPhone Array with Dictionary with Array (ListApp)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm working on a list app. I have two arrays (Animals and Cars). The code looks like:

...

Edit:

This is the new code of the whole .m with your suggestions:
Now it works that everything is in one list. Now how to group them in the list?

```
#import "ListeViewController.h"

@interface ListeViewController ()

@end

@implementation ListeViewController{

    NSArray *kategorien;
    NSArray *autosArray;
    NSArray *tiereArray;
    NSArray *kategorienArray;
    NSArray *combined;
    NSDictionary *allgemein;

}


-(instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self){
        self->kategorien = @[@"Autos", @"Tiere"];
        self->autosArray = @[@"Opel", @"Mercedes", @"Audi"];
        self->tiereArray = @[@"Hamster", @"Ente", @"Schwan", @"Pferd", @"Pinguin"];
        self->combined = [autosArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tiereArray];
        self->allgemein = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: combined forKeys:combined];


    }

    return self;
}

-(instancetype) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        self->kategorien = @[@"Autos", @"Tiere"];
        self->autosArray = @[@"Opel", @"Mercedes", @"Audi"];
        self->tiereArray = @[@"Hamster", @"Ente", @"Schwan", @"Pferd", @"Pinguin"];
        self->combined = [autosArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tiereArray];
        self->allgemein = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: combined forKeys:combined];

    }

    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*) tableView{

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [combined count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                    }
                    }
                    //Configure the Cell

                    cell.textLabel.text = [combined objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                    return cell;
                    }



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"In did Select Row At Index Path");
    NSLog(@"Row %d" ,indexPath.row);

                    }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

(sry or the german tagging of the arrays and the dictionary, also sry for some spelling and grammar)

Comment: Who taught you to use `self->xxx`? Have you studied properties and how to use them? Why do you need a dictionary?

Comment: im working on a bigger application in a group. and its for training, but nobody knows how to handle with that. in the bigger app there we have to put in ads. and the ads are managed with this type of dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NSDictionary's dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to create an NSDictionary based on two arrays.

The way you would do it would be:

```
self.allgemein = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:autosArray forKeys:tiereArray];
```

If you want to combine both arrays and then store them in a Dictionary with the same keys and objects (although why you would do this I'm not sure) then do:

```
NSArray *combined = [self.autosArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.tiereArray];
self.allgemein = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:combined forKeys:combined];
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Until here I understand. But ow to handle it, when "autosArray" and "tiereArray" both are the arrays for dictionary and for keys? 
Do I now have to write `self.allgemein = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:autosArray, tiereArray forKeys:autosArray, tiereArray];` ?

Comment: If I understood correctly you are trying to create a dictionary where the keys are the tiereArray and the objects are the autosArray? i.e.: @{@"Hamster" => @"Opel", @"Ente" => @"Mercedes" ... }

Comment: If you are trying to create a Dictionary with the keys and objects being the same and a combination of both the tiereArray and the autosArray then see my edited answer.

Comment: thx. first problem is cleared. now the other (pls look my edit).

Comment: Group them by what? Can you edit your question to show how you expect your data to look?